# iOS 13 UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier

Tags: ios13, xcode11, swift5

Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier , or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

```
self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
     if self.backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid{
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
                self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            }
})
```

Comment: Have you achieved this.

Comment: Any answers? I am seeing the same problem?

Comment: How do we add the breakpoint in the first place?